# Magento2 - Order status shows closed on zero subtotal order

Tags: magento2, orders, magento2.3.5, magento2.3.5-p1

I have free downloadable products on my Magento 2 shop (`Magento 2.3.5 p1`).

If a customer purchases a free downloadable product, he gets a zero subtotal order which I set Zero Subtotal Checkout to status processing via Magento Payment settings automatically.

This closes the order automatically and does not allow the customer to download his product. If I set the status to `'Pending'...` then I have to generate a manual invoice to enable customer to download his order.

This behaviour was not observed in Magento 1, there it was always ending with status `"complete"` and the download was enabled automatically.

Means I get customers complaining because they can't download their zero total orders.

A zero total order should allow status to invoiced automatically. Fix required for this problem.

Comment: You can do this with littel customization into this and done that one.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known bug on magento 2.3.x
See here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25177

I m just adding the solution here but it is just from this ticket:

```
Reference Class: Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Handler\State

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Handler\State" type="Vendor\VirtualOrderStatus\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Handler\State" />
</config>



public function check(Order $order)
    {
        $currentState = $order->getState();
        if ($currentState == Order::STATE_NEW && $order->getIsInProcess()) {
            $order->setState(Order::STATE_PROCESSING)
                ->setStatus($order->getConfig()->getStateDefaultStatus(Order::STATE_PROCESSING));
            $currentState = Order::STATE_PROCESSING;
        }

        if (!$order->isCanceled() && !$order->canUnhold() && !$order->canInvoice()) {
            if (in_array($currentState, [Order::STATE_PROCESSING, Order::STATE_COMPLETE])
                && !$order->canCreditmemo()
                && !$order->canShip()
                && ($order->getGrandTotal() > 0 || $this->isFreePaymentFullyRefunded($order)) // check if it is free payment and also all refunded
            ) {
                $order->setState(Order::STATE_CLOSED)
                    ->setStatus($order->getConfig()->getStateDefaultStatus(Order::STATE_CLOSED));

            } elseif ($currentState === Order::STATE_PROCESSING && !$order->canShip()) {
                $order->setState(Order::STATE_COMPLETE)
                    ->setStatus($order->getConfig()->getStateDefaultStatus(Order::STATE_COMPLETE));
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

    private function isFreePaymentFullyRefunded(Order $order)
    {
        $totalInvoicedItem = 0;
        $totalRefundItem = 0;

        foreach ($order->getItems() as $item) {
            $totalInvoicedItem += $item->getQtyInvoiced();
            $totalRefundItem  += $item->getQtyRefunded();
        }

        return $totalRefundItem > 0 && $totalRefundItem == $totalInvoicedItem;

    }
```